# Create a functor from a MPL metafunction class

Tags: c++, boost, boost-mpl

I've been looking for a class in MPL that will create a function object from a sufficiently well-behaved MPL metafunction class. I hand-rolled this implementation:

```
  template <class Lambda, class Result>
  struct functor
  {
      typedef Result result_type;

      template <typename Type>
      Result operator()( Type ) 
           { return Lambda::template apply<Result>::type::value; }
  };
```

A usage example would be

```
  Foo foo;
  return functor< boost::mpl::always<boost::mpl::int_<5> >, int >( foo );
```

as a glorified version of writing `return 5`.

As this operation seems pretty basic, I'd have thought there is already a similar class in MPL, but a search of the documentation didn't yield anything for me. Am I missing something?

Comment: On reading the clarifying comments, Boost Fusion might be what you are looking for. It does this: a fusion of meta and runtime programming (note that Fusion comes with it's own Sequence (and derived) Concepts. However, MPL Sequences are adapted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is such a class in Boost.MPL, since they focus exclusively on compile-time computations. This kind of wrapper would rather be held in [Boost.Fusion](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/index.html), which aims at making the link between compile and runtime entities, but I did not found anything.

I think you will have to use your own implementation, which seems alright at a glance (even though I would rather use [`mpl::apply`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/apply.html) to handle placeholder expressions). I think you could also omit the return type, since it can be deduced from the lambda.

Here is an alternate implementation using `apply` and deducing the return type from the lambda:

```
template < typename Lambda >
struct functor
{
    template < typename Type >
    typename boost::mpl::apply< Lambda, Type >::type::value_type 
    operator()( Type ) 
    { 
        return boost::mpl::apply< Lambda, Type >::type::value; 
    }
};

// sample use:
int main()
{
    boost::mpl::int_<5> five;
    std::cout << functor< boost::mpl::identity< boost::mpl::_ > >()( five );
    // Output "5"
}
```

Comment: exclusively... except for e.g. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/for-each.html

Comment: @sehe: You are right, I forgot `for_each` (I must admit that I never had to use it).